# crystal reports justify text

Tags: crystal-reports

Does anyone know how to justify the text in a text field ??
or this option doesn't exist in crystal reports

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be right there next to all the others. If you think you're missing the entire toolbar, bring it back by right clicking on the toolbar area and turning on the Formatting toolbar. (Picture is of Crystal XI Developer)

[image: Pic of Location]

Answer (score 0):

It does.  I don't have Cyrstal Report with me but it should be the Alignment property in the Font/Text tab of the property menu.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to justify text within an actual text box rather than justify page positioning...

Right click on the text object, select format object. If it is a number object, select the Common tab and you'll see a horizontal alignment dropdown. If it's text, select the paragraph tab in format object and you'll see horizontal alignment there.